# Declaration of structure in header (linked list) in C

Tags: c, struct, header-files

I'm learning C with "Learn C The Hard Way," and in exercise 32, I found this code in a header file:

```
struct ListNode;

typedef struct ListNode {
    struct ListNode *next;
    struct ListNode *prev;
    void *value;
} ListNode;

typedef struct List {
    int count;
    ListNode *first;
    ListNode *last;
} List;
```

my question is, why does the author write:

```
struct ListNode;
```

and then continue with the typedef:

```
typedef struct ListNode {
    struct ListNode *next;
    struct ListNode *prev;
    void *value;
} ListNode;
```

Is there a reason for declaring the struct before defining it in a typedef?

Comment: when reading "learn c the hard way", you should be aware that [it is considered a bad resource by some](http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/Main_Page#Stuff_that_should_be_avoided). links and references to books to material considered "acceptable" can also be found on that site. as [illustrated here](http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/Snippets#Defining_a_structure_that_has_a_pointer_member_to_its_own_type), you can actually use `typedef struct ListNode ListNode;` before `struct ListNode { ListNode *next; ListNode *prev; void *value; };` and it's perfectly ok, too.

Comment: Your links will help me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some people do this for unknow reason or because a coding standard requires it. There is no actual need (and IMO this makes the code less readable as it adds useless redundancy).

For `typedef struct ListNode`, this already works as a forward declaration of the incomplete type `struct ListNode`.

For the second `typedef`, the struct tag (second part of `struct List`) is of little use, as you do not need a forward declaration and will likely only use the `typedef`ed alias later on.

You could also go completely without `typedef` and use `struct ListNode`/`struct List` in your code. My personal opinion is to use `typedef`s everywhere, but I would also accept consistent use of the former. I just would not mix both, as that will lead to confusion ("do I have to add `struct` for this type or not?").

Comment: I think that the author declare these structures for implement a LinkedList and I don`t know why the second structure is useless.

Comment: +1, but your last paragraph is a bit unclear, you mean the name `List` in `typedef struct List` is useless right?

Comment: @Purag: Yes, the struct tag is of little use. I hope the edit makes it more clear.

Comment: @VanesaGarcía: Please read my edit. The former version was a bit missleading.

Comment: @VanesaGarcía Olaf's point is that for the `ListNode` struct, since the struct contains pointers to the struct itself, you need the tag there since it has not been `typedef`ed yet. For the `List` struct, you don't really need the tag since you will likely not use `struct List` anywhere in the code, and especially not in the struct itself. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Purag +1, but in the rest of code, the author use List as type in parameters function. Then, is necesary the fordward declaration of ```List```?

Comment: No, because that's what the `typedef` does. The author could have done `typedef struct { stuff } List` and you'd be able to use `List` as a type everywhere.

Comment: @VanesaGarcía: A _forward declaration_ is only required if you need to reference a type **before** it has been completely declared. As the type is inclomplete at the time of this declaration, there are only limited usages allowed, basically only to declare a pointer to such a `struct`.This solves the recorsion problem if a `struct` has to reference its own type (the `List` is **the** typical example for such). You cannot use the `typedef` alias, as that is not defined until the `;` after its name has been processed by the compiler.

Comment: I Already  understood. Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ListNode;
```

This is  separate forward declaration. Old compilers require this type of declarations.May be related to an older standard, or an incomplete standard implementation

`struct` forward declarations can be useful when you need to have looping struct declarations.

Comment: But I don´t understand why the author don´t do same for the second structure?

Comment: What do you mean by "old"? AFAIR it already worked with K&R C without the forward declaration, as the `struct ListNode` in the `typedef` already works as incomplete declaration of the type.

Comment: @VanesaGarcía Did you try the code without *that* statement?

Comment: @this no, because I want to know what does mean these statements

Comment: @VanesaGarcía: That's why I provided an answer.